# Did a gust of wind make me lose my hat?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2020, secret-hat

Yesterday I "won" a secret hat in the shape of a flag (sorry, I only remember the initial of his name "V")

[image]

but today it is no longer on my list of hats.

Since it is a secret hat, I don't know why I received it and why I lost it. Maybe due to a gust of wind?

Comment: There also a list of all hats, so when you're looking for one, you'll find it there: [Winter Bash 2020 hat list  ](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/357915)

Comment: I somehow got that hat 3 times... (all in SO)

Comment: But you got it back, it seems :-D

Comment: @Tomerikoo that was cool. I think this was supposed to happen once but I realize that this could happen multiple times.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From [Yaakov Ellis](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56450361) in the Winter Bash 2020 chat room:

> **Hat Maintenance Note:** I fixed a bug in the secret definition of Vexillologist, removed the hat from all users (since a good number who earned it should not have, based on a bug in the sql) and reawarded to all users who should earn it. Anyone who is earning it now will get a new WB inbox notification. So if you are trying to figure out the hat, just look at hats awarded from [now - 5 minutes] and on.

So your observation is correct. You might have had the Vexillologist hat but that hat was removed if you only got the hat due to the bug.

Comment: It seems we're now missing a Buggy Hat for those who got hat demotions due to bugs :)

Comment: I was wondering why one of my hats went away and which one it ones. It is the "Vexillologist" apparently since I remember having it but a I don't know, and I raised a helpful flag yesterday. I guess I have to raise another to get it back.

Answer (score 3):

An important note is that while hats can be taken from your closet (eaten by bugs (moths)) the employees (gust of wind) can't [blow off a hat on your head](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56468522#56468522) - so you get to [keep hats that are being worn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358230/disciple-hat-is-missing-in-the-earned-hat-list#comment1196456_358230), regardless or bugs or wind.

Removed hats that are retroactively earned after the rules are altered are re-awarded after a recalculation. New hats are awarded subject to the current (possibly new) rules.

This is why you retained your Vexillologist hat on Stack Overflow, even though it doesn't appear in your list of currently owned hats.

Comment: Oh wow, that's interesting. Thanks for adding that note. I assumed that the hat would be removed, such that *if* you take it off, you wouldn't be able to put it back, but it doesn't sound like that's the case.

Comment: Actually... my assumption was correct, [as confirmed by a CM](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/51180968#51180968).

Comment: This is interesting. The hat can be eaten by moths or blown by gusts of wind virtually.